# Redshift won't change column type

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, type-conversion, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to change a column in Redshift from varchar to integer. I've already checked and the strings are all numbers so it should force fine.

When I run:

```
alter table schema.table_name alter column "id" type int;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: target data type "int8" is not supported [SQL State=0A000]

I've checked the [Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html) and just to rule out a few potentials:

- The field is not a primary or foreign key
- There's no compression encodings on it
- There's no default values
- The code is not in a transaction block

Any pointers would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: there is way around make add a new column and migrate all the data of existing column to new column den delete the old and rename the new added column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter column type is for varchar types - "ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_data_type --
A clause that changes the size of a column defined as a VARCHAR data type."  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html

Comment: Thanks Bill, can't believe I missed that!